# Make all Ruby Hashes HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to make all hashes that you deal with in Ruby On Rails a HashWithIndifferentAccess? There are so many times that I try to access a hash with a symbol instead of a string such as say for Model.attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: override the initializer of Hash... but I'd not trade standard Class for convenience

Answer (score 2):

```
::Hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Very bad idea, though.

Comment: Lol, would a better solution be to open up the Hash class, modify `def []` such that if it cannot find the symbolized version, to see if it exists for the String? Is there a good way to do this such that it only affects the Hashes that I directly deal with? Or should I just not even try to make this easier because I will just end up doing something terrible?

Comment: why is this a bad idea? And can you override the `{ }` object, i.e. `{ }.class == HashWithIndifferentAccess`?